# How to place to TextView on one line, second TextView should take 3rd part of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/movie_icon" 
                android:src="@drawable/star_off" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="left"          
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:text="aaaaa"/>                 
     <TextView android:id="@+id/time"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:text="1:25 - 2:25"
         android:layout_height="74dip" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:gravity="right"
         android:layout_weight="2"
         android:background="@drawable/time_background"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`time` and `name` TextViews have the same width, but I need to have width of `time` equal to the half width of `name`. How can I do it? Or, how to create `name` width fixed (for ex., 100dip)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making both of their widths 0 and set weight="1" for the one you want smaller, and weight="2" for the one you want bigger. If that doesn't do it how you want, I am not sure that there is any way to do it without setting a fixed width for them like 100dip as you mentioned.

Comment: `layout_width` can not be zero and it must be defined (if I don't define that, it displayed correctly, but when run returns application error).  How to follow 2nd approach then?